# Compile two Wifi drivers together

Tags: drivers, wireless, monitor, realtek

I have two drivers (let’s say A and B) for my Alfa Awus036ACH, which are "rtl8812au".

The [A driver](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au) supports very well mode monitor, but not the AP mode...
The [B driver](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux) badly supports mode monitor but supports well AP mode...

What I want to do is "create" one driver on the basis of those two previous, so as to merge their best capacities...

Is that possible?
Do I need to get the installation config file "Mode monitor" of the A driver and replace it by the one of B driver?

Comment: Of course !! There they are : https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au and https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Comment: There is no easy way to combine drivers. You might look for a newer driver that supports both already. Check [here](https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au-driver-5.2.20). It may or may not have monitor mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... If there is no easy way to do it, is there a hard way ? Doesn't matter if I must learn how to compile a new driver...